# Boost ASIO - Unable to read packet header from body

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I use Boost ASIO and I would like to separate header from body message.

Here is my opcode enum:

```
enum ServerOpcode : uint16_t{
    SMSG_AUTH_CONNECTION_RESPONSE                    = 0x001,
    SMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST_RESPONSE                      = 0x002,
    SMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST_RESPONSE_TEST                 = 0x1A6,
};
```

Here is how I send message:

```
boost::asio::io_context io_context;
std::vector<tcp::socket> sockets;
for (int i = 0; i < connectionsNumber; ++i) {
    try
    {
        sockets.emplace_back(io_context);
        tcp::socket& s{sockets.back()};
        tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
        boost::asio::connect(s, resolver.resolve( defaultIP,config.GetConfigValue("AuthServerPort", defaultPort)));

        enum { body_length = 1024 };
        enum { header_length = 8 };
        enum { max_length = body_length +  header_length};
        char header_[header_length];
        char body_[body_length];
        char data_[header_length + body_length];

        ServerOpcode opc;
        opc = ServerOpcode::SMSG_LOGIN_REQUEST_RESPONSE_TEST;
        std::string message = "I am testing here!!!";


        snprintf(header_,header_length,"%x",opc);
        strcpy(body_, message.c_str());
        sprintf(data_, "%s %s", header_, body_);

        size_t request_length = sizeof(data_)/sizeof(*data_);
        std::cout << "Header: " << header_ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "body: " << body_ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "whole message is: " << data_ << std::endl;
        std::cout << "size: " << request_length << std::endl;
        std::cout << "max size: " << max_length << std::endl;

        boost::asio::write(s, boost::asio::buffer(data_, request_length));

    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
```

}

Here is how I read it on the server:

```
void Vibranium::Client::read_header() {
    auto self(shared_from_this());
    boost::asio::async_read(socket,
    boost::asio::buffer(_packet.data_, _packet.header_length),
    [this, self](boost::system::error_code ec, std::size_t /*length*/)
    {
        if (!ec)
        {
            std::cout << "Header: " << std::endl;
            std::cout.write(_packet.data_, _packet.header_length);
            std::cout << "\n";
            //read_body();
        }
        else
        {
            std::cerr << "Invalid header sent!" << std::endl;
        }
    });
}
```

`Packet.h`:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include "string"
#include "Protocol/ServerOpcode.h"

class Packet {
public:
    Packet() : body_length_(0)
    {
    }
    enum { max_body_length = 1024 };
    enum { header_length = 8 };
    char header_[header_length];
    char body_[max_body_length];
    char data_[header_length + max_body_length];
    char * body();
    void PreparePacket(ServerOpcode serverOpcode, std::string message);
    std::size_t body_length() const;
private:
    std::size_t body_length_;
};


#endif //VIBRANIUM_CORE_PACKET_H
```

However I see output as:

```
New Connection (ID: 4)
Header: 
1a6 I am
```

That is not correct! Why `Header:` is showing `1a6 I am`? Where is my mistake?
I am expecting it to be just `1a6`. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line after reading:

```
std::cout.write(_packet.data_, _packet.header_length);
```

header_length is 8 = length of '1a6 I am'

Your header length should be 3 (not 8), if you want to have '1a6' only.

Comment: Blagodarq ti Komsho!

Comment: Nema za shto :)

Answer (score 0):

This line: `snprintf(header_,header_length,"%x",opc);` should have a newline character at the end of it if you're going to print it. If that's the case, you should extend your buffers by one to allow for a newline. Or better yet, print the expected characters and specify the specific length whenever they need to be printed (as you're doing on the server):

```
            std::cout << "Header: " << std::endl;
            std::cout.write(_packet.data_, _packet.header_length);
            std::cout << "\n";
```

As the code is written now, the output continues (in contiguous memory), until the next newline character is hit.

Additionally, I'd recommend using `vector<uint_8>` instead of arrays as they allow for bounds checking and allow for default moveable/copyable semantics for the `Packet` type. You may also consider using the `boost::asio::buffer` type.